# Emacs whitespace mode change color of the text

Tags: emacs, whitespace, syntax-highlighting

In emacs 25.3, I enable 'whitespace' mode, it changes the color of the text.
See this example, the 2nd line, 'private' is now grey.

Can you please tell me how can I fix this?

[image]

Comment: Please provide a step-by-step recipe to reproduce the problem, starting from `emacs -Q` (no init file). State what you see at each step and what you expected to see instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you have an overly long line.  You probably want to do one of:

- remove `lines` from `whitespace-style`
- modify `whitespace-line` face
- increase `whitespace-line-column`

Get more help with `C-h v whitespace-style` and `M-x customize-group whitespace`

---

For reference, my whitespace config is just:

```
(setq whitespace-style '(newline space-mark tab-mark newline-mark))
```